# Configure Azure AD redirects in dotnet core

Tags: .net-core, azure-active-directory

I have created an APP in Azure App registrations. I have given the redirect URL as
http://localhost:60671/security/signincallback. My current application which dotnet core web application is running at http://localhost:61442. After successful authentication it is redirecting me to http://localhost:61442/security/signincallback instead of http://localhost:60671/security/signincallback

I have this in my startup class

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

            services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
            {
                options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/";
                options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken;
                options.CallbackPath = "/security/signincallback";
                options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
                {
                    OnTokenValidated = OnTokenValidated,
                };
            });
```

I am not sure which part of my code is saying it to redirect to a certain endpoint. Is there a way to configure this?

Comment: The callback URL is under your app definition in Azure AD. Go to the portal and amend it. It is NOT controlled by your code.

Answer (score 0):

The OpenID Connect authentication handler uses the current request URL + callback path that you specified to set the redirect_uri parameter.

I tried to specify a redirect URI manually to AAD with localhost + different port from what is in the app registration and it was not accepted.
Double-check your app registration,
the URL with port 61442 should be there.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `http://localhost` to "Redirect URIs":

[image]